# Map.put using generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, covariance

I get errors with the following code (as described below the snippet):

```
public class MyClass {
  private Map<String, Subclass1> mapToSubclass1;
  private Map<String, Subclass2> mapToSubclass2;

  public void update(
      final boolean updatesAreSubclass1,
      final List<? extends Superclass> updates) {

    Map<String, Superclass> mapToUpdate;
    if (updatesAreSubclass1) {
      mapToUpdate = mapToSubclass1;
    } else {
      mapToUpdate = mapToSubclass2;
    }


    updates.stream().forEach((entity) -> {
      mapToUpdate.put(entity.getId(), entity);
    });
  }
}
```

where `Subclass1` and `Subclass2` extend `Superclass`, and `Superclass` provides `public String getId();`.

As written, I get errors when attempting to define mapToUpdate - `Incompatible types. Required: Map<String, foo.bar.Superclass>, Found: Map<String, foo.bar.Subclass1>` (or Subclass 2, in the else-clause).

If I change mapToUpdate to a `Map<String, ? extends Superclass>`, I get an error when attempting to `put` - `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'foo.bar.Superclass', required '? extends foo.bar.Superclass'`

I *think* this is to do with the notion of covariance, but I'm not sure how to resolve the problem. A couple of solutions I came up with, neither satisfactory:

- Should I need two `update` methods, one for each Subclass (This gets messy quickly if there are more than two)?
- Should I move the `put` inside the `if (updatesAreSubclass1)` clause, and cast `updates` to the appropriate `List<Subclass>`?

Comment: I dont know if I understood properly, but isn't it okay to just cast the subclass map to mapToUpdate? 
            mapToUpdate = (HashMap<String, Subclass1>) (Map) mapToSubclass1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work with an infinite number of possible subclasses since as far as I can tell you are just creating a map of class plus Id -> Superclass.

```
private Map<Class,Map<String,Superclass>> map = new HashMap<>();
void update(List<? extends Superclass> l) {
    l.stream().forEach(o -> put(o));
}

public void  put(Superclass obj) {
    String id = obj.getId();
    Map<String,Superclass> submap = map.get(obj.getClass());
    if(null == submap) {
        submap = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(obj.getClass(), submap);
    }
    submap.put(id, obj);
}

public Superclass get(Class clss, String id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(map)
            .map(m -> m.get(clss))
            .map(m2 -> m2.get(id))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing the best way to solved this problem is creating two update methods. One for `Subclass1` and one for `Subclass2`. The reason is simple, better have two single method which do one thing, than one method with boolean parameter which does two things.

This code looks nice and is more testable.

```
public void update1(final List<Subclass1> updates) {
    updates.stream().forEach((entity) -> {
        mapToSubclass1.put(entity.getId(), entity);
    });
}

public void update2(final List<Subclass2> updates) {
    updates.stream().forEach((entity) -> {
        mapToSubclass2.put(entity.getId(), entity);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?rq=1)

Normal inheritance doesn't work in generics. So, `Map<String, Subclass1>` doesn't extend from `Map<String, SuperClass>`.

Your option would be to cast the **object** explicitly.

```
if (updatesAreSubclass1) {
    updates.stream().forEach((entity) -> {
      mapToSubclass1.put(entity.getId(), (SubClass1) entity);
    });
} else {
    updates.stream().forEach((entity) -> {
      mapToSubclass2.put(entity.getId(), (SubClass2) entity);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method does not make a lot of sense with regard to inheritance. You have two separate maps of subclasses and want to add superclass instances in either one of them. I would suggest thinking of a more proper way to deal with this use case.

However, if you want to keep things the way they are, this will do the trick:

```
public void update(
            final boolean updatesAreSubclass1,
            final List<? extends Superclass> updates) {
  updates.stream().forEach((entity) -> {
    if(updatesAreSubclass1)
      mapToSubclass1.put(entity.getId(), (Subclass1) entity);
    else
      mapToSubclass2.put(entity.getId(), (Subclass2) entity);
    });
}
```

You cannot store `Superclass` objects in a map that is defined for a subclass without explicit casting. This should make you think that there may be something wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this:

```
mapToUpdate = mapToSubclass1;
```

because then your code could go on to add non `Subclass1` objects to `mapToUpdate` and the compiler wouldn't be able to flag it (i.e., it wouldn't be able to provide type safety).

One way around this is to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing" and not use generics for your `mapToUpdate` variable.  Like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void update(final boolean updatesAreSubclass1,
        final List<? extends Superclass> updates) {

    if (updates.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Map mapToUpdate;
    if (updatesAreSubclass1) {
        mapToUpdate = Collections.checkedMap(mapToSubclass1, Integer.class,
                Subclass1.class);
    } else {
        mapToUpdate = Collections.checkedMap(mapToSubclass2, Integer.class,
                Subclass2.class);
    }

    updates.stream().forEach(
            (entity) -> {
                System.out.println("Adding..." + entity.toString()
                        + " to map " + mapToUpdate.toString());
                mapToUpdate.put(entity.getId(), entity);
            });
}
```

The caveat is that you really do need to know what you are doing, because if you call `update` with `updatesAreSubclass1` = `true`, when the list is not really a list of `Subclass1` objects, you'll get a `ClassCastException` at runtime.

NOTE: you'll get the `ClassCastException` because we're using `Collections.checkedMap`.  If you leave that out, you won't get an exception, but you'll get `Subclass2` objects in your `mapToSubclass1` map -- even worse, right?

Comment: This approach would be safer if `update` inspected the list rather than relying on the caller to tell it what type of list it's getting.